# What makes overflow in leetcode #695 Max Area Island

Tags: c++

I met some problems in leetcode #695.
I don't understand why my code gets overflow result.
Here are my code of c++.
Wish to get favor for me to point out where I made mistake.
Thanks a lot.

Question:

> You are given an m x n binary matrix grid. An island is a group of 1's
> (representing land) connected 4-directionally (horizontal or
> vertical.) You may assume all four edges of the grid are surrounded by
> water.
>
> The area of an island is the number of cells with a value 1 in the
> island.
>
> Return the maximum area of an island in grid. If there is no island,
> return 0

[Link to problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/max-area-of-island/)

Input is

> Input: grid =
> [[0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0],[0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0],[0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0]]
> Output: 6 Explanation: The answer is not 11, because the island must
> be connected 4-directionally.

And here is my solution:

```
/*
 * @lc app=leetcode id=695 lang=cpp
 *
 * [695] Max Area of Island
 */

// @lc code=start
class Solution {
public:
    vector<vector<bool>> mark;
    
    int calculate(vector<vector<int>>& grid, int i, int j, int row,int col){
        
        int buf_up, buf_down, buf_left, buf_right = 0;
        cout<<"i="<<i<<";j="<<j<<endl;
        
        if(mark[i][j] == true) return 0;

        if(mark[i][j] == false){
            cout<<"into mark false\n";
            mark[i][j] = true;
            cout<<"mark["<<i<<"]["<<j<<"]="<<mark[i][j]<<"\n";
        }

        if(grid[i][j] == 0) return 0;

        int c_buffer = 1;
        cout<<"initial c_buffer="<<c_buffer<<endl;
        //up
        if((i-1)>=0 && grid[i-1][j] == 1 && mark[i-1][j] == false){
            cout <<"up" <<endl;
            cout<<"before buf_up="<<buf_up<<"" <<endl;
            buf_up = calculate(grid, i-1, j, row, col);
            cout<<"after buf_up="<<buf_up<<"" <<endl;
            //cout<<"buffer="<<buffer<<endl;
        }
        //down
        if((i+1)<row && grid[i+1][j] == 1 && mark[i+1][j] == false){
            cout <<"down" <<endl;
            
            cout<<"before buf_down="<<buf_down<<"" <<endl;
            buf_down = calculate(grid, i+1, j, row, col);
            cout<<"after buf_down="<<buf_down<<"" <<endl;
            //cout<<"buffer="<<buffer<<endl;
        }
        //left
        if((j-1)>=0 && grid[i][j-1] == 1 && mark[i][j-1] == false){
            cout <<"left" <<endl;
           
            cout<<"before bufbuf_left_up="<<buf_left<<"" <<endl;
            buf_left = calculate(grid, i, j-1, row, col);
            cout<<"after buf_left="<<buf_left<<"" <<endl;
            //cout<<"buffer="<<buffer<<endl;
        }
        //right
        if((j+1)<col && grid[i][j+1] == 1 && mark[i][j+1] == false){
            cout <<"right" <<endl;
            
            cout<<"before buf_right="<<buf_right<<"" <<endl;
            buf_right = calculate(grid, i, j+1, row, col);
            cout<<"after buf_right="<<buf_right<<"" <<endl;
            //cout<<"buffer="<<buffer<<endl;
        }
        cout<<buf_up <<"|"<< buf_down <<"|"<< buf_left <<"|"<< buf_right <<"\n";
        
        c_buffer = c_buffer+ buf_up + buf_down + buf_left + buf_right;
        cout<<"end c_buffer="<<c_buffer<<endl;
  
       
        return c_buffer;
    }
    int maxAreaOfIsland(vector<vector<int>>& grid) {
        int res = 0;
        int max = 0;
        int buffer = 0;
        int row = grid.size();
        int col = grid[0].size();
        vector<vector<bool>> save(row, vector<bool>(col,false));
        mark = save;
        for(int i = 0; i< row; i++ ){
            for(int j=0;j<col;j++){
                if(grid[i][j]==1){
                    
                    buffer = calculate(grid,i,j,row,col);
                    cout<<"final_buffer="<<buffer<<endl;
                    if(buffer>max){  
                        max=buffer;
                        
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        //[[1,1,0,0,0],[1,1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1,1],[0,0,0,1,1]]\n
        //[[0,1,1],[1,1,0]]\n
        return max;
    }
};
// @lc code=end
```

Error:

> Runtime Error
> ✘ Error: Line 59: Char 59: runtime error: signed
> integer overflow: 808925107 + 1610678760 cannot be represented in type
> 'int' (solution.cpp)
> ✘ Error: Line 59: Char 59: runtime error:
> signed integer overflow: 808925107 + 1610678760 cannot be represented
> in type 'int' (solution.cpp)
> SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer:
> undefined-behavior prog_joined.cpp:68:59

I think this means in some directions have overflow values. After I tracked them, they didn't into any directions condition and then c_buffer turned to overflow values.

My stdout:

```
 i=0;j=2
into mark false
mark[0][2]=1
initial c_buffer=1
32765|4|0|0
end c_buffer=32770
final_buffer=32770
i=0;j=7
into mark false
mark[0][7]=1
initial c_buffer=1
down
before buf_down=0
i=1;j=7
into mark false
mark[1][7]=1
initial c_buffer=1
right
before buf_right=0
i=1;j=8
into mark false
mark[1][8]=1
initial c_buffer=1
right
before buf_right=0
i=1;j=9
into mark false
mark[1][9]=1
initial c_buffer=1
805338995|512|0|0
end c_buffer=805339508
after buf_right=805339508
805338995|256|0|805339508
end c_buffer=1610678760
after buf_right=1610678760
808924978|128|0|1610678760
```

I refused that values of buf_up, buf_down, buf_left, buf_right are 808924978,128,0,1610678760.
I don't know what reason make this result.
Thank you.

Comment: Please extract a [mcve] and provide that, not just the code above, which people here can't run. In any case, research the error message, that should give you an idea what it's about.

Comment: did you check for the boundary condition... like the first condition to be checked inside the recursion function must be something like
` if (r < 0 || c < 0 || r >= grid.length || c >= grid[0].length || grid[r][c] == 0 ) return 0`. We need to check for the boundary

Comment: `if((i-1)>=0 && grid[i-1][j] == 1 && mark[i-1][j] == false){` - what do you think happens when `i` is 0 and `grid[i-1]` gets evaluated?

Comment: @selbie You reminded me this condition.

Comment: @RohithV I missed this big issue.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Thank you for reminding.. I'll be much careful next time.

Comment: And thanks for all you point the problem out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified your code a little bit and added the boundary check condition at the very beginning. The problem was with one of your check on that boundary which results in overflow

```cpp
// @lc code=start
class Solution {
public:
    vector<vector<bool>> mark;
    
    int calculate(vector<vector<int>>& grid, int i, int j, int row,int col){
        if (i < 0 || j < 0 || i >= row || j >= col || grid[i][j] == 0 || mark[i][j] == true)
            return 0;
        mark[i][j] = true;
        int buf_up, buf_down, buf_left, buf_right = 0;
        int c_buff = 1;
        buf_up = calculate(grid, i-1, j, row, col);
        buf_down = calculate(grid, i + 1, j, row, col);
        buf_left = calculate(grid, i, j - 1, row, col);
        buf_right = calculate(grid, i, j + 1, row , col);
        c_buff += buf_up + buf_down + buf_left + buf_right;
        return c_buff;
        
    }
    int maxAreaOfIsland(vector<vector<int>>& grid) {
        int res = 0;
        int max = 0;
        int buffer = 0;
        int row = grid.size();
        int col = grid[0].size();
        vector<vector<bool>> save(row, vector<bool>(col,false));
        mark = save;
        for(int i = 0; i< row; i++ ){
            for(int j=0;j<col;j++){
                if(grid[i][j]==1){
                    
                    buffer = calculate(grid,i,j,row,col);
                    cout<<"final_buffer="<<buffer<<endl;
                    if(buffer>max){  
                        max=buffer;
                        
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        //[[1,1,0,0,0],[1,1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1,1],[0,0,0,1,1]]\n
        //[[0,1,1],[1,1,0]]\n
        return max;
    }
};
// @lc code=end
```

This is accepted and please try to check for the boundary before any operation.

Comment: Thank you. You survived me a lot. I found out where I made mistake. I had a growth class from you.